# ODOO 12 server error regarding invoice sequencing

Tags: database, odoo, pgadmin

I am trying to change the sequence of my invoicing. Instead of resetting it each new year, I can keep the count going upwards continuously.

(for example)

- inv/2021/0001 date 1/1/2023   (this one should be 2366)
- inv/2021/2365    date 31/12/2022
  [image]

researching on the subject I found out I need to go into technical -> sequences to get the invoice numbers I want.

but my problem is, once i click sequences I get the following server error:

```
Error:
Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 1039, in get
    value = self._data[key][field][record._ids[0]]
KeyError: 254

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/fields.py", line 981, in __get__
    value = record.env.cache.get(record, self)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 1041, in get
    raise CacheMiss(record, field)
odoo.exceptions.CacheMiss: ('ir.sequence(254,).number_next_actual', None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 656, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 314, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 87, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 698, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 346, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/service/model.py", line 97, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 339, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 941, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 519, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 904, in search_read
    return self.do_search_read(model, fields, offset, limit, domain, sort)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 926, in do_search_read
    offset=offset or 0, limit=limit or False, order=sort or False)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/models.py", line 4589, in search_read
    result = records.read(fields)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/models.py", line 2791, in read
    vals[name] = convert(record[name], record, use_name_get)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/models.py", line 5117, in __getitem__
    return self._fields[key].__get__(self, type(self))
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/fields.py", line 985, in __get__
    self.determine_value(record)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/fields.py", line 1098, in determine_value
    self.compute_value(recs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/fields.py", line 1052, in compute_value
    self._compute_value(records)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/fields.py", line 1043, in _compute_value
    getattr(records, self.compute)()
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_sequence.py", line 96, in _get_number_next_actual
    seq.number_next_actual = _predict_nextval(self, seq_id)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_sequence.py", line 68, in _predict_nextval
    self.env.cr.execute(query % {'seq_id': seq_id})
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/sql_db.py", line 148, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/sql_db.py", line 225, in execute
    res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "ir_sequence_1000015" does not exist
LINE 6:                FROM ir_sequence_1000015
```

I believe it could be a database error but I am not sure what this is about. Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you recently migrated your Odoo version or your database between instances?

Comment: not at all, this database have been in use since the last 3 years

Comment: now i believe the error as read from the first 6 lines.


comes from some failure in the invoice sequencing in the database maybe a long time ago to keep the year sequence (this odoo is working since 2019)

as you can see in the capture, the sequencing is wrong, it never changed to 2022, and now it did not change neither to 2023, the expected behaviour is to change the second field to the current year.